# how to scale azure function based on queue size

Tags: azure-functions, queue

I see references to a scale controller, but havent seen documentaion on how to configure this controller
any help is much appreciated!

i am running a function v3 in c# that sees the queue mesages  fine . i am just looking to handle larger volume next

Comment: What is your volume- express it in messages per second. Have you seen the Premium namespace that you could use? Is your function app running as Consumption plan or premium/dedicated?

Comment: running under consumption plan but can switch
the scaling  would need to be based on count in a queue which can be 1/2 a million per day at times

Comment: You should start with running in Consumption plan, and Standard tier of ASB, based on the behaviour you could upgrade to premium, which supports autoscaling of message units, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/automate-update-messaging-units)